# How to use Betafix with the Coxphw package in R?

Tags: r, regression, cox-regression

I am trying to use the coxphw package to fit a weighted cox model and force a fit for a particular Beta “FC” to be greater than 0.

When I enter the code:

```r
wcox.m <- coxphw( Surv(CCE,Status) ~ Y1RT + Y1 + Y1SQ + Y1*B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5 + Y1*B6 + C2 + C3 + LEG + FC + Y1*G,
                  betafix = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.16, NA),
                  data = d, jack = TRUE)
```

I am getting the error:

> “Error in IOARRAY[2, ] <- fixed : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length”

I think the problem might be the interaction terms? I tried explicitly stating the linear and interaction terms (as below) but got the same error as above.

```r
wcox.m2<-coxphw( Surv(CCE,Status)~ Y1RT + Y1 + Y1SQ + BASC + B1 + Y1*B1 + B2 + B3 + B4 + B5 + B6 + Y1*B6 + C2+ C3 + LEG + FC +G + Y1*G,
                 betafix = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.16, NA),
                 data = d, jack = TRUE)
```

Adding or removing an NA from the betafix vector (in either case) gives the error:

> “Error in coxphw(Surv(Cumulative_Credits_Earned, Status_Variable) ~ Y1RT + : The number of model terms in formula and the length of betafix must be identical.”

Any suggestions?

Sample code to generate the issue:

```r
set.seed(5)
library(coxphw)
library(coxed)
simdata <- sim.survdata(N=1000, T=100, num.data.frames=1)
model1 <- coxphw(Surv(y, failed) ~ X1 + X2 + X3+ X1*X2,betafix = c(NA, NA, 0.3), data=simdata$data)
model2 <- coxphw(Surv(y, failed) ~ X1 + X2 + X3+ X1*X2,betafix = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.3), data=simdata$data)
model3 <- coxphw(Surv(y, failed) ~ X1 + X2 + X3+ X1*X2,betafix = c(NA,NA,NA, NA, 0.3), data=simdata$data)
```

Edit: I emailed the creator of the package, who recommended creating a new variable, i.e. x1x2<-x1$data*x2$data and calling that instead of x1*x2 in the formula.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I've added code that generates the issue.

Comment: Maybe reach out to the [package maintainers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coxphw/index.html)? This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Phil, I did. The response was to compute a new field i.e. x12<-x1*x2 and call that instead.

Comment: Please answer your own question for future users running into the same problem.